# How to send a kill signal to multiple child processes in case of failure doing a task?

Tags: c, signals, fork

I'm trying to make a program that creates up to 4 child processes. Each child will use a search function to find a certain word in a desired file:

> bool search(char *file,char *word,int section)

**P.S: You can ignore the search function and what does it *exactly* do as the main quest here is to send a signal to multiple child processes upon the success of a certain child process.**

Each child process will search in a certain section of the file. i.e a file named "foo" that containts:

> car
>
> bar
>
> tar
>
> far

the child processes are looking for the string "bar".

If a child process succeeds in finding the string, it will exit with value 0(***exit(0)***), otherwise if it finished its whole section with no sucess of finding the string it will exit with value 1(***exit(1)***).

Once a child exists with value 0(succeded in finding the string). The parent will send a kill signal to the other child processes.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
    pid_t p;
    p=fork();
    int i;
    int storage[4];
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        p=fork();
        if(p==0)
        {
            storage[i]=getpid();
            open("testfile.txt",O_WRONLY);
            if(search("testfile.txt","bar",i))
            {
                storage[i]=1;
                //exit(0);
            }
            else
                //exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(storage[i]!=1)
            kill(stroage[i],SIGTERM);
    }
}
```

What I did in this code is using an array of 4 integers, it contains the ids of the child processes. The case of the child that succeded is changed to 1. Afterwards I sent a kill signal to the other processes except for that specific process.

Is the code I wrote correct? If so How do I use the exit values to send the signal without using the array?

Comment: `storage` is an object with automatic storage duration. It is certainly not shared between the processes, so your approach will absolutely not work.

Comment: @EOF I think I get it, the 4 child processes will have their own memory field of the variable storage, right? That's why it isn't going to work as the parent will have no values in the variable? What if I use it as a pointer? Would that solve it?

Comment: A pointer would only solve this if it pointed to memory that is shared between the processes. In that case, you would also have to ensure atomicity and order of accesses to the shared memory.

Comment: Apart from the problems already stated, in any case this approach would, even if possible, only be feasible once all the processes have finished running, since until they've all finished executing, you don't know if one of the ones still executing is going to exit with status code 1, but just hasn't done so yet. Since you have to wait for them all the finish executing, you won't be needing to send them any signals at all.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I'm not waiting for them all to finish, only one has to finish with status code 0, then the parent will send a kill signal to the other processes who hasn't finished yet(Some might finish with status code 1 before one finishes with status code 0, which is a not success).

Comment: @Amine : I know you're not doing this, but your code doesn't work. As currently written, you don't wait for any of your processes to finish at all - you fork them, check them once, then exit. I'm saying you'd need to do this in order for your proposed approach to work, in order to accomplish what you want by making one pass through an array of exit statuses. Obviously the code you actually posted is broken in many ways, some of which have already been described.

Comment: @Amine : if you actually did wait for the processes to finish, as you should, then none of this would be necessary; you'd just check the exit status directly, and if you find a successful one, you kill any child processes that are still running.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths what about this piece of code `tmp=wait(&waitstatus);
 do
 { if(exitstatus==0)
  {
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
    if(storage[i]!=tmp)
     kill(storage[i],SIGTERM);
   }
  }
 }while((exitstatus=WEXITSTATUS(waitstatus))>0);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can run a unix command to get the list of child process IDs using cmd() if you don't want to use the arrays.

Also fork() returns the child process ID to the parent.  The parent can store it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the child's pids in the array in shared memory, to do that you probably should create separate .h file with the following content.

```
struct shared_arr {
    int is_full;
    int pids_arr[4];
};
```

You could access that shared structure using the following snippet:

```
int shm_id = shmget((key_t) 12345, sizeof(struct shared_arr), 0666| IPC_CREAT);

//get the shared data
struct shared_arr *shared_data;
void* shared_memory = (void*) 0;
shared_memory = shmat(shm_id, (void*)0,0);
if(shared_memory == (void *) -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "shmat FAILED\n");
}
shared_data = (struct shared_arr *) shared_memory;

//init shared data with zeros
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SHARED_ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    shared_data->pids_arr[i] = 0;
}
```

details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems

Also, consider setting process group id and send a signal to all processes in the same process group, using just one kill call.

details about set group id: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-setpgid/ 
about kill: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Your last approach (in the comment) is better, but still has bugs.

For one, the `wait` is outside of the loop (it's executed only once)
and the `exitstatus` variable is undefined in the first iteration - it's assigned only when control reaches the `while(...)`.

I propose something similar to this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t p, pids[4];
    // Why did you want to fork here? 
    int i;
    int finder = 1; // Which process can find 'bar'
    int status;
    char signal_name[256];

    printf("[Parent] pid=%d\n", getpid());

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        p=fork(); // fork makes a new process, for a new thread use clone
        if (p==0) {
            printf("[Child %d] ppid=%d, pid=%d\n", i, getppid(), getpid());
            usleep(((random() % 1000) + 500) * 1000); /* microseconds */
            printf("[Child %d] %s\n", i, finder==i ? "found" : "not found");
            if (finder==i) /* the pseudosearch result */
                exit(0);
            else
                exit(1);
        } else {
            pids[i] = p;
            printf("[Parent] childpid=%d\n", p);
        }
    }

    while (pids[0]>0 || pids[1]>0 || pids[2]>0 || pids[3]>0) {
        printf("[Parent] something happened\n");
        p = wait(&status);
        if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) {
            printf("[Parent] child with pid=%d exited with code 0\n", p);
            for (i=0; i<4; i++)
                if (pids[i] > 0 && pids[i] != p) {
                    printf("[Parent] killing child %d (with pid=%d)\n", i, pids[i]);
                    kill(pids[i], SIGTERM);
                }
            break;
        } else if (WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            if (WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("[Parent] child with pid=%d exited with code %d\n", p, WEXITSTATUS(status));
            else {
                dprintf(2, "[Parent] child with pid=%d was terminated by signal %d: ", p, WTERMSIG(status));
                psignal(WTERMSIG(status), "");
            }
            for (i=0; i<4; i++)
                if (pids[i] == p)
                    pids[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
[Parent] pid=28375
[Parent] childpid=28376
[Parent] childpid=28377
[Child 0] ppid=28375, pid=28376
[Parent] childpid=28378
[Child 1] ppid=28375, pid=28377
[Parent] childpid=28379
[Parent] event received
[Child 2] ppid=28375, pid=28378
[Child 3] ppid=28375, pid=28379
[Child 0] not found
[Child 1] found
[Parent] child with pid=28376 exited with code 1
[Child 2] not found
[Parent] event received
[Parent] child with pid=28377 exited with code 0
[Parent] killing child 2 (with pid=28378)
[Parent] killing child 3 (with pid=28379)
```